# Ambigous naming within eval results in TypeError: unsupported expression type: <class 'function'>

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a `DataFrame` with columns `min` and `sec`. I wanted to calculate `time` column (in minutes) with `pd.DataFrame.eval()`.

```
df.eval('time = min + sec / 60')
```

However it resulted in error:

> TypeError: unsupported expression type: class 'function'

I guess it is because `min` is read as function that calculates minimum and therefore doesn't refer to column called `min`. Is there a way to escape that behaviour without changing column name? I know I could write `df['time'] = df['min'] + df['sec'] / 60`, but I'm wondering specifically about `eval()` usage.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.It is because it is considering one of the name as function (here its min) , and hence the error. Apart from that you really cant do anything without changing column name. You can change the column name temporarily and rename it later, but I get it thats not what you want, Also you can always do `df['time'] = df['min'] + df['sec'] / 60`

I tried different ways, but there is no other way.You have answered your question.
Also according to eval rules the string cannot contain any Python statements, only Python expressions.